# Module for "Force Control"

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, robotics

I am looking for a device (e.g motor) for an Arduino or Raspberry which can change its force. You can imagine it as a servo but instead of controlling it through positioning it is controlled with "applied force". Therefore you could provide a value for the force and then the motor seeks to "press" against something with the given force.

I could also imitate this behaviour by using a stepper motor and control it with a digital potentiometer, but isn't there a special module for exactly this case?

Comment: Product recommendations are prohibited in this site actually, so your question might be closed. But what are you trying to do? Maybe that would be a better question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a torque motor.

This is easy to achieve with a brushed motor, fed with a constant current. Internal friction and higher order terms aside, the output torque is proportional to the current. Use the MCU to drive a DAC, or programmable current source, to drive the motor. Depending on the force accuracy you require, you probably do not need force feedback to trim the current, you can just control the current and rely on the motor's proportionality.

It would need force feedback to do with a stepper or brushless motor.

While you can run the motor up to its rated current for a short while like this, bear in mind that if it is at a standstill, then it probably has less cooling than if it was running at rated speed, so might overheat. Stay well below the rated current, or run only briefly, or provide some additional means of cooling the rotor.